# Estimate number of clients using Joint Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, joint-distribution

I have a server able to observe from which country a client makes a request. Then, my server gives me the distribution of clients (on a 24h basis).

Let's say that we have :

```
Belgium: 10%
Canada: 40%
China: 50%
```

Now, I know that I have a defined number of clients in two cities in each country. Let's say :

```
Belgium_city1: 10000
Belgium_city2: 5000
Spain_city1: 20000
Spain_city2: 15000
China_city1: 40000
China_city2: 60000
```

I would like to estimate the number of clients originating from each city and make a request to the server.

The solution given by my professor is to just multiply the number of clients of one city by the probability of the country where the city is located.

For Belgium_city1 as example : 10000*0.1 = 1000 clients requesting my server

But I don't understand the rationale of this solution. I tried the joint distribution like this.

```
Let A = client comes from Belgium
Let B = client comes from Belgium_city1
```

$P(A,B) = P(B|A)P(A)$

where :

```
P(A) = 10% as observed by the server
P(B|A) = P(Belgium_city1)/[P(Belgium_city1)+P(Belgium_city2)] = 10000/15000
```

Then my probability a client requests the server from Belgium_city1 is P(A, B) = 10000/15000*0.1.

Now to estimate the number of clients making requests from Belgium_city1, I'm not sure how to do it. The only way to find 1000 as my professor said is to multiply my previous probability by the total number of clients in Belgium.

But why should I have to do that? This is not clear to me. I think I should multiply by the total of clients from each country and not only Belgium.

Can someone explain where is the mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have relevant information. You have information on the distribution of traffic, but it doesn't say how many requests were made. For example, there could be 5 requests from China, 4 from Canada, and 1 from Belgium. As you can see, those numbers do not necessarily have much to do with the total number of customers. To calculate this, you would need to know $P(\text{request} \,|\, \text{country})$ rather than $P(\text{country} \,|\, \text{request})$ (what you have). You could use the Bayes theorem here, but you need additional data, like $P(\text{request})$ (the probability that a customer makes a request).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! That's what I thougt, then I imagine my professor can do this estimation under a specific assumption but I don't see which one

Comment: @M.Warzowski you should ask them about that.

Comment: I think I found the solution. The context is that this computation is part of an estimation in one part of my master thesis. Then I found that :
P(A) = 0.1 (probability client comes from Belgium)
P(B)  = 10000/150000 (probability a client comes from BelgiumCity1)
If we make the assumption that event are independent to get a first estimation, we find that P(A,B) = P(A)*P(B) = 0.1*1/15 then to have an estimation of clients making request from BelgiumCity1 we multiply this result by total number of clients and we found 0.1*10000 clients as stated by my professor, what do you think?

Comment: Of course we make another assumption that all client takes part in requests @Tim
♦